# Handle null in LINQ sum expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am using a LINQ query to find sum of a column and there is a slight chance that the value might be null in few cases

The query I am using now is

```
int score = dbContext.domainmaps.Where(p => p.SchoolId == schoolid).Sum(v => v.domainstatement.Score ?? 0);
```

where `domainstatement` can be null and score also can be null

Now after executing this query, I am getting the error

> The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

So how can I handle null exceptions effectively and return sum as an INT value?

Comment: int score = dbContext.domainmaps.Where(p => p.SchoolId == schoolid).Sum(v => (v?.domainstatement?.Score).GetValueOrDefault());

Does that work? Because the default value for an integer is 0 the summation of this should work without a hitch, but I don't know if I got the syntax correct.

Comment: Is there a `domainstatement` id?

Comment: Are you really using LINQ-2-SQL rather than EF?

Comment: @JonathanAllen its Entity frameworks

Answer (score 15):

Here

```
Sum(v => v.domainstatement.Score ?? 0);
```

you've just put the null-coalescing operator on the wrong place. Usually such error is solved by promoting the non nullable type to nullable (no `DefaultOrEmpty` and null checks are needed), but here you already have a nullable type, and with null-coalescing operator you did the opposite of what the error message is telling you - *the query must use a nullable type*.

Simply move it *after* the `Sum` call and the issue is gone:

```
Sum(v => v.domainstatement.Score) ?? 0;
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `DefaultIfEmpty` extension method:

```
int score = dbContext.domainmaps.Where(p => p.SchoolId == schoolid 
                                         && p.domainstatement != null)
                                .DefaultIfEmpty()
                                .Sum(v => v.domainstatement.Score ?? 0);
```

Your problem is there are not entities with that `schoolId`.Something like this is the sql code is going to generate:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int = 3
DECLARE @p1 Int = 0
-- EndRegion
SELECT SUM([t3].[value]) AS [value]
FROM (
    SELECT COALESCE([t2].[Score ],@p1) AS [value]
    FROM (
        SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
        ) AS [t0]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT [t1].[Score ]
        FROM [domainmaps] AS [t1]
        WHERE [t1].[SchoolId] = @p0
        ) AS [t2] ON 1=1 
    ) AS [t3]
```

Comment: This won't throw a null reference exception if v.domainstatement == null?  That's awesome thanks for the pointer!

Comment: This will cause a null ref exception. Instead, you should add the filter of removing domain maps where v.domainstatement is also null. `.Where(p => p.SchoolId == schoolid && p.domainstatement != null).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum(v => v.Score ?? 0);`

Comment: You're right @TravisJ, if the relationship is optional, then it could be null, thanks

Comment: I am getting error at  DefaultIfEmpty as Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<QCIApp.Models.domainschoolmap>' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery<int>'

Answer (score 2):

Some time Yours domainstatement Context null so used to linq query

```
int score = dbContext.domainmaps.Where(p => p.SchoolId == schoolid && p.domainstatement!=null && p.domainstatement.Score!=null).ToList().Sum(v => v.domainstatement.Score);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int score = dbContext.domainmaps.Where(p => p.SchoolId == schoolid).Sum(v => (v?.domainstatement?.Score).GetValueOrDefault());
```

The default value of any int? is 0.  So this should work.

Comment: I don't think that the null conditional operator is supported by query providers.

Comment: @TravisJ that's interesting.  I was really hoping that the op would respond with a yes or no to whether or not that worked.  I don't have a dbContext example that I can try this out on otherwise I would.